# Access SQL query - select date range from specific day of the month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been scratching my head over this for a while, but i would like to make a query that selects values from the 24th of the current / last month to the 24th of the next/current month depending on the month we are in - this is basically from one payroll to the next. any suggestions on the SQL query?

So for instance - if the current date is the 20th March then i would want all data from 24th Feb to the 24th March, but if the date was over the 24th of this month say 30th March then i would want data from 24th March to 24th April - if that makes sense.

Thanks,
Phill

Comment: What do you mean by *depending on the month we are in*?

Comment: So for instance - if the current date is the 20th March then i would want all data from 24th Feb to the 24th March, but if the date was over the 24th of this month say 30th March then i would want data from 24th March to 24th April - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this expression:

```
iif(
  day(date()) >= 24,
  dateserial(year(date()), month(date()), 24),
  dateserial(year(dateadd('m', -1, date())), month(dateadd('m', -1, date())), 24)
)
```

you can get the starting date of your condition (though I'm not sure about the `>=` sign, maybe it should by just `>`? ), so use it like this:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, ... 
from (
  select *, 
    iif(
      day(date()) >= 24,
      dateserial(year(date()), month(date()), 24),
      dateserial(year(dateadd('m', -1, date())), month(dateadd('m', -1, date())), 24)
    ) as start_date
  from tablename
) as t
where t.date_column between t.start_date and dateadd('m', 1, t.start_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract 23 days and extract the year and the month:

```
select year(dateadd("d", -23, datecol)) as year,
       month(dateadd("d", -23, datecol)) as month
```

Answer (score 0):

For a slimmer method, use *DateAdd* and *DateDiff*:

```sql
Select *
From YourTable
Where DateDiff('m', DateAdd('d', -23, [YourDateField]), DateAdd('d', -23, Date())) = 0
```